# How to get the logits of the model with a text classification pipeline from HuggingFace?

Tags: python, huggingface-transformers, sentiment-analysis, huggingface, large-language-model

I need to use `pipeline` in order to get the tokenization and inference from the `distilbert-base-uncased-finetuned-sst-2-english` model over my dataset.

My data is a list of sentences, for recreation purposes we can assume it is:

`texts = ["this is the first sentence", "of my data.", "In fact, thats not true,", "but we are going to assume it", "is"]`

Before using `pipeline`, I was getting the logits from the model outputs like this:

```
with torch.no_grad():
     logits = model(**tokenized_test).logits
```

Now I have to use pipeline, so this is the way I'm getting the model's output:

```
 selected_model = "distilbert-base-uncased-finetuned-sst-2-english"
 tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(selected_model)
 model = AutoModelForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained(selected_model, num_labels=2)
 classifier = pipeline('sentiment-analysis', model=model, tokenizer=tokenizer)
 print(classifier(text))
```

which gives me:

`[{'label': 'POSITIVE', 'score': 0.9746173024177551}, {'label': 'NEGATIVE', 'score': 0.5020197629928589}, {'label': 'NEGATIVE', 'score': 0.9995120763778687}, {'label': 'NEGATIVE', 'score': 0.9802979826927185}, {'label': 'POSITIVE', 'score': 0.9274746775627136}]`

And I cant get the 'logits' field anymore.

Is there a way to get the `logits` instead of the `label` and `score`? Would a custom pipeline be the best and/or easiest way to do it?

Comment: I'm going to answer you but I hope you're being nice if I need more clarification. And this question is good and the context is clear since I know the other quesiton.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you use the default `pipeline`, the postprocess function will usually take the softmax, e.g.

```
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModelForSequenceClassification

tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained('distilbert-base-uncased-finetuned-sst-2-english')
model = AutoModelForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained('distilbert-base-uncased-finetuned-sst-2-english')


text = ['hello this is a test',
 'that transforms a list of sentences',
 'into a list of list of sentences',
 'in order to emulate, in this case, two batches of the same lenght',
 'to be tokenized by the hf tokenizer for the defined model']

classifier(text, batch_size=2, truncation="only_first")
```

[out]:

```
[{'label': 'NEGATIVE', 'score': 0.9379090666770935},
 {'label': 'POSITIVE', 'score': 0.9990271329879761},
 {'label': 'NEGATIVE', 'score': 0.9726701378822327},
 {'label': 'NEGATIVE', 'score': 0.9965035915374756},
 {'label': 'NEGATIVE', 'score': 0.9913086891174316}]
```

So what you want is to overload the postprocess logic by inheriting from the pipeline.

To check which pipeline the classifier inherits do this:

```
classifier = pipeline('sentiment-analysis', model=model, tokenizer=tokenizer)
type(classifier)
```

[out]:

```
transformers.pipelines.text_classification.TextClassificationPipeline
```

Now that you know the parent class of the task pipeline you want to use, now you can do this and still enjoy the perks of the precoded batching from `TextClassificationPipeline`:

```
from transformers import TextClassificationPipeline

class MarioThePlumber(TextClassificationPipeline):
    def postprocess(self, model_outputs):
        best_class = model_outputs["logits"]
        return best_class

pipe = MarioThePlumber(model=model, tokenizer=tokenizer)

pipe(text, batch_size=2, truncation="only_first")
```

[out]:

```
[tensor([[ 1.5094, -1.2056]]),
 tensor([[-3.4114,  3.5229]]),
 tensor([[ 1.8835, -1.6886]]),
 tensor([[ 3.0780, -2.5745]]),
 tensor([[ 2.5383, -2.1984]])]
```

Comment: That was it! Thanks! Nice class name :)